# How to change user role names in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, roles

I have a Wordpress site that was set up in French, meaning some database table fields and files are in French. I have since changed the site language to English, but some French language still exists.

The main thing that needs changing is user role names. They look like this currently - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRm3p.jpg

I don't know how to change these:
1. Gestionnaire Boutique > Shop Manager.
2. Client > Customer.

Help please!

Thanks, Harry

Comment: There is a plugin called `Advanced access manager` . I used to use it. Download it and install, I think you will be able to modify roles.